# XSL html tag not rendered as html in parameterized string in property file

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

Hi I have a problem rendering a certain element in a parameterized string value in property file in a xslt2.0 .

I have a property file with a property like this:

```
user.no_reply=Add {0} to your address book to make sure that you receive our notifications
```

My template:

```
<xsl:template name="disclaimer">

    <xsl:param name="notification-sender"/>

    <text type="text">
        <xsl:attribute name="stringParam0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$notification-sender"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>user.no_reply</xsl:text>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

And the parameter that I expect to be passed to the template.

```
<xsl:call-template name="disclaimer">
                    <xsl:with-param name="notification-sender">
                        <text type="link" new-line="false">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">mailto:<xsl:value-of select="notificationSender"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'text-decoration: underline; color: #868686'"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <xsl:value-of select="notificationSender"/>
                        </text>
                    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The output is this:

> Add to your address book to make sure that you receive our
>   notifications

The email is not filled so there is a blank space where the parameter was.

Was I expect is to have the full html in the string:

```
Add <a href="mailto:whatever" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #868686">whatever</a>  to your address book to make sure that you receive our notifications
```

If I use the value-of the given parameter only the value inside the anchor tags is displayed. Any ideas how I can achieve the expected behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your property file is related to your XSLT but in your XSLT you create a result `text` element with an attribute node `stringParam0` you seem to want to populate with the serialized representation of some other result element (i.e. the `xsl:copy-of select="$notification-sender"` seems to try that). However, an attribute value is constructed from the string of the `select` expression or sequence constructor (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-attributes, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content) so you can't expect any XML markup to appear in an attribute value unless you put it there explicitly.

If you can, move to XSLT 3 (in the Java world supported by the open source Saxon HE 9.8 or 9.9) and use the XPath 3 `serialize` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-serialize in

```
<xsl:attribute name="stringParam0" select="serialize($notification-sender)"/>
```

or of course directly in

```
<text type="text" stringParam0="{serialize($notification-sender)}">..</text>
```

For XSLT 2 you will need to check whether your XSLT 2 processor supports an extension similar to the XSLT/XPath 3.0 `serialize` function or you will need to implement it yourself or use existing libaries like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.